# ASP.NET MVC 5 Аутентификация на нескольких доменах с помощью форм

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Доброго дня! Имеются сайты a.contoso.com, b.contoso.com, contoso.com. Умею аутентифицироваться с помощью FormsAuthentication на одном домене. Необходимо, чтобы при аутентификации с помощью форм на одном из этих сайтов, на всех сайтах IsAuthenticated был true, а также при выходе из аккаунта на одном из сайтов IsAuthenticated выставлялся false на остальных тоже. Как это реализовать? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поддомены используют одну и ту же БД для хранения учётных данных пользователя - это уже хорошо. Вы не уточнили, используете ли Вы ***Web Api***, так как в тегах указан ***Web Api***. Если же используете, то это решает множество проблем, так как запись в куки будет происходить на домене-хосте, и кукисы с разных поддоменов будут храниться с привязкой к этому домену-хосту.

Пример:
Если **a.contoso.com** и **b.contoso.com** - это клиентские приложения сервиса, размещённого на домене **contoso.com** - то при авторизации с домена **a.contoso.com** будут привязаны к хосту **contoso.com**, из чего следует то, что войдя на домен **b.contoso.com** вы будете авторизованы (в теории)! Почему это происходит? Потому что кукисы записывает серверное приложение и хранит в браузере с привязкой к своему домену (т.е. contoso.com), и не важно из под какого домена вы будете авторизовываться (хотя и в поддоменах Вы тоже можете хранить свои кукисы). Если есть вопросы - пишите, отвечу в комментариях!